# why doesnt notepad++ in Wine display the filenames properly?

Tags: wine

Tiny yet strange issue:

[image]

In the list of files/folders, notepad++ running in Wine completely ignores the last character. Other than that it works perfectly under Wine, so this is very strange to me. Also a quick google didn't yield any other people with this issue...

It started to get really annoying in a folder where all my html files have a number in the name, at the end.

Versions:

- Notepad++: v5.9.3.  (downloaded from the official website, followed an irretrievable guide to install)
- Wine: 1.2.2.

Comment: can you confirm where you downloaded notepad++ from?  also what version of wine are you using?

Comment: I updated the post with version details. Do you think reinstalling Notepad++ would help?

Comment: possibly - did you use the installer or just run the exe extracted from the zip?

Comment: I installed it.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a corruption in your wine install.

To test this, temporarily move your current wine folder to a backup and recreate a new wine folder

```
mv ~/.wine ~/.wine_backup
winecfg
```

then reinstall notepad++

```
wine npp.5.9.3.Installer.exe
```

If the same problem occurs, remove the new folder and rename back the old folder

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
mv ~/.wine_backup ~/.wine
```

Note - I've tested notepad 5.9.3 using wine version 1.3.26 and it works perfectly.